# Jsoup parsing not showing content between <body> tags

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I tried to parse http://jobs.hasbro.com/search using `Jsoup` but the content between  tags didn't show for some reason. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jobs.hasbro.com/search").get();
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(doc.html()));
```

I tested with other random websites and saw that the parse was working ok. I am using `Jsoup 1.7.2` and `JDK 1.7`

Comment: Can you show us the code that is not working?

Comment: I edited and put in the codes above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `userAgent` in your request

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://jobs.hasbro.com/search")
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                            .timeout(0).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();
        System.out.println(document.html());
```